# Write Integer Value to a File and Read it

Tags: java, file-io

I got a Follower-check function in my twitch.bot and i need a read/write solution for it.

It should do the following:

Read an given Number(int) out of the file
Write a new Number to the file and delete the old one
Create the file if it doesnt exist

(the File needs only to store 1 number)

So how can i do this?

right now, i got a String Reader and as soon as i read it i parse it into an INT but i only got errors so i think it doesnt work that way so im searching an option for writing/reading the int already without parsing it from a string.

```
import java.io.*;
public class FollowerChecker {
public static StringBuilder sb;
    static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        try {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();

            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();

        }
    }



    public static void Writer() {

        FileWriter fw = null;

        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("donottouch.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.write(TwitchStatus.totalfollows);


        try {
            fw.write(sw.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any dummy code which proves your attempt ??

Comment: Search about serialization.

Comment: added the Code.   BTW the site (stackoverflow) looks not like it used too?? its liek a simple Dark-blue design and im irritated why its liek that now.. i didnt changed anything :/ any idea how i can reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be way more complicated than it should be.  If you just want to write a number without parsing it as text you can do this.

BTW You may as well use a `long` as it will use the same disk space and store more range.

```
public static void writeLong(String filename, long number) throws IOException {
    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))) {
        dos.writeLong(number);
    }
}

public static long readLong(String filename, long valueIfNotFound) {
    if (!new File(filename).canRead()) return valueIfNotFound;
    try (DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FieInputStream(filename))) {
        return dis.readLong();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        return valueIfNotFound;
    }
}
```